# Confusion concerning the Euclidean Norm and unitary invariance on $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, invariance

For a unitarily invariant norm on $\mathbb C^n$, how do I show that $||x||=||x||_2||e_1||$? I can show that $||e_1||=1$ for the Euclidean norm by definition, and is therefore unitarily invariant, does that suffice as proof?

I've been told that the only unitarily invariant norm on $\mathbb C^n$ satisfying the above equality (that $||e_1||=1$) is the Euclidean norm, would someone help me understand why that is?

Note that $e_1$ is the elementary $n\times1$ col vector, $[1,0,0,...0]^T$

Comment: Good question, ***+1, endorsed!***  But I think in your last line you might want to drop the ${}^T$ or else say that $e_1$ is a *column* vector.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis, hey this has gone a few days without answer, and I'm not sure how to ask for help. Is there a right way to do that without just reposting the question (which feels against the spirit of Stack)

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to address you question.  Been tied up with "real world" business.  Will try to get to it before too long.